# develop drag and drop widgets using Angular JS

Tags: user-interface, widget

we are planning to build a product for our usage and need some input/advise on how we can develop drag and drop widgets, these widgets should be configurable and should be able to connect/link with other widgets on a canvas, was looking at mulesoft product and we really liked on how its built

Answer (score -1):

The HTML5 specification has a native "drag and drop" support. Do you really need to do this with Angular? I reccomend you read this very simple example of what I´m talking about:

[Drag and Drop Simple example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)

More detailed stuff:

- [HTML5 Rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)
- [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_drag_drop.htm)